# python: subtraction of timestamps fails due to omitted leading zeros in microsec

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Iam using python 3.6 and need to subtract two timestamps:

> timestamp1 = 2017-02-27 16:01:40
>
> timestamp2 = 2017-02-27 00:00:00.000480

My first attempt was to: 
`newTimestamp = timestamp1 - timestamp2`
which also subtracts year, date, etc. I do only want to subtract hour to microsecond.

```
newTimestamp = timestamp1 - datetime.timedelta(hours=timestamp2.hour, minutes=timestamp2.minute, seconds=timestamp2.second, milliseconds=timestamp2.microsecond)
```

This will however return the following wrong result:
newTimestamp = 2017-02-27 16:01:39.520000

Returning what .microsecond&co. does:

```
timestamp2.hour =  0

timestamp2.minute =  0

timestamp2.second =  0

timestamp2.microsecond = 480
```

As you can see: timestamp2.microsecond deletes the leading zeros and makes out of 000480 -> 480000 which is totally wrong. I could use

```
format(timestamp2.microsecond), '06d'
```

to add the leading zeros but will get a string with which I cannot subtract the dates....

With a second timestamp its getting really interesting:

> timestamp1 = 2017-02-27 16:01:40
>
> timestamp2 = 2017-02-27 00:00:00.994424

```
timestamp2.second = 0

timestamp2.microsecond = 994424
newTimestamp = 2017-02-27 15:45:05.576000
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance.

//edit1: it seems like my problem does not come due to the leading zeroes but it seems like the last 3 digits of the microsecond are being used are the first 3 digits of the microsecond while the actual first 3 digits of the microsecond are being used as minute?and second?

//edit2: jupp, just found this neat .compoments function, suspicions confirmed:

```
print('newTimestamp : ', newTimestamp .components)    
Components(days=0, hours=16, minutes=1, seconds=38, milliseconds=999, microseconds=513, nanoseconds=0)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Are you forgetting about milliseconds?
Date formats are year-month-day hour:minute:second.mmmuuu.

The math on your first timedelta looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already found my mistake:
newTimestamp = timestamp1 - datetime.timedelta(hours=timestamp2.hour, minutes=timestamp2.minute, seconds=timestamp2.second, milliseconds=timestamp2.microsecond)

Should be:

newTimestamp = timestamp1 - datetime.timedelta(... microseconds=timestamp2.microsecond)´

I have mistaken millisecond for microsecond. Took forever to find out :)